# Restricting space at the beginning

Tags: sapui5

This is function which is I'm using at `liveChange` event:

```js
if (oEvent.mParameters.value.indexOf(" ") === 0) {
  sap.m.MessageToast.show("Space character is not allowed");
  oEvent.preventDefault();   
  return false;
}
```

By using this code I have to restrict the whitespaces at the beginning in the input field. I tried a lot, I'm getting the message but it is taking the whitespace. How can I make an input field display only  message and it should not take whitespaces.

Comment: What is the input field about in the first place? Is it numbers only? Certain ID with a fixed length? What is the user defining with that input value? With more context, you can get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "invasively" remove the whitespace in the beginning of the input, you can do something like this:

```
onLiveChange = function(oEvent) {
  var sValue = oEvent.getParameter('value');
  if (sValue[0] === ' ') { // or use sValue.match(/^ /)
    oEvent.getSource().setValue(sValue.trimStart());
    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Space character is not allowed");
  }
}
```

Also have a look at this [SAPUI5 Demokit Sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputChecked/preview) as well as the `validationError` and `validationSuccess` events of class [`sap.ui.core.Core'](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Core/events/Summary) to get an idea of the recommended way of handling validation.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working very nicely. @rikusv

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to use the match function to check the leading spaces and then trim the value if leading spaces are present?

Comment: Thanks d01ph1n. Not sure whether it would make a difference to computation or readability, but I have updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: First code is working fine and it is same as second code.